# Can't figure out how to upload file and json in form data react

Tags: node.js, json, express, multipartform-data, mern

I'm building a MERN stack web app and I want the users to be able to upload post with an image and post data.
The data looks like this:

```
  title: 'The war in Ukraine continues',
  text: 'Volodymyr Horbenko is the latest official to lose his job after Mr Zelensky said bosses failed to root out pro-Russian elements in the agency',
  sources: [
    'https://www.bbc.com/news/world-62223264',
    'https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2022/jul/19/russia-ukraine-war-live-news-putin-and-erdogan-to-meet-us-weaponry-stabilising-frontlines-ukraine-military-chief-says',
  ],
  locations: [
    {
      description: 'boutcha',
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-122.479887, 38.510312],
    },
    {
      description: 'kyiv',
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [-122.582948, 38.585707],
    },
  ],
};
```

now I also want to upload a picture this is just a photo that comes from an input.
I know that I should use formData to send the picture and i've tried uploading the data as well like this:

```
 const form = new FormData();
 form.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
 form.append('imageCover', fileInputRef.current.files[0]);
 axios.post('/api/v1/stories/', form);
```

but when it comes to the backend I haven't been able to figure out how to retrieve the data into the request body. I've tried using multer `app.use(multer.single('data'));`(which works fine for the pictures) and `app.use(express.json({ type: 'multipart/form-data' }));`
but I get Error: Unexpected end of form, and Error:Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0 errors respectively.
also, if there is another way of sending both form data and files i'd like to hear about it, keep in mind that because there are nested objects I can't simply write `form.append(key,value)` for each pair in the data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.post("/api/v1/stories", multer().single("imageCover"), function(req, res) {
  var file = req.file;
  var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
});
```